# How to upload multiple images using single input and without using multiple attribute in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, php-7

I would like to upload multiple images using single input tag(**with image preview**) and without use multiple attribute in input tag, I have used following script but i could not help it always take last input image in array not whole images.

**HTML**

```
<form id="profile-photos-form" class="profile_image_gallery" name="profile_image_gallery" action="{{ URL::to('create_profile')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="mdb-lightbox no-margin " id="result">
            <input type="file" name="photos[]" id="files">

            <div class="width-33 gallary-image-profile-pic">
                <!-- Following is only for set profile image from upload images -->
                <a class="spotlight" href="">
                    <img class="photo_class" name="profile_image"  src="" class="img-fluid">
                    <input type="hidden" name="profile_pic" id="profile_pic" value="">
                </a>
            <div class="icons-images">
            <i class="fa fa-plus icon_delete_add" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-trash icon_delete_add" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;"></i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Uploaded image preview will show here -->
            <div id="thumb-output"></div>
        </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function(){    
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader){
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");        
        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){            
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");            
            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)            {
                var file = files[i];                
                //Only pics
                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                  continue;                
                var picReader = new FileReader();                
                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){                    
                    var picFile = event.target; 
                    console.log(picFile)                   
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
                    div.classList.add("width-16");
                    div.classList.add("gallary-image");

                     div.innerHTML = "<img name='image_gallery[]' class='photo_class' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";        



                    output.insertBefore(div,null);



                });
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        });
    }else{
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

**PHP Laravel Controller code**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\escortProfile;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\NotActivatedException;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Checkpoints\ThrottlingException;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Activation;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redire;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;
use App\Mail\UserRegistration;

use App\UserDetails;
use App\User;
use App\Roles;
use App\Locations;
use DB;
use Response;
use File;
use App\Http\Middleware\Admin;

class profileController extends Controller{
    public function createProfile(Request $request){   
       if ($image = $request->file('photos')) {            
            foreach ($image as $files) {           
                $destinationPath = 'public/image/'; // upload path
                $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
                $insert[]['image'] = $profileImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code only return last input image in array not return all the images, I want all the images and also move all the uploaded images in folder and database.

NOTE: currently i have not written DB store code.

Comment: This is likely because you ask for ‘photos’, not ‘image_gallery’ in $request->file call.

Comment: "I would like to upload multiple images using single input tag and without use multiple attribute in input tag" What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: This does not seems right because upload control comes with this property and it must be used to enable multiple upload feature from one file input control <input type="file" name="name" multiple>